# Jquery Treeview plugin does not work in new mvc4 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Im trying to run this plugin
https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-treeview

In clear html it works, so it means the problem is in my mvc code.

I have following code

```
<!-- TREEVIEW Plugin -->
<link href="/Content/jquery-treeview/jquery.treeview.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/Content/jquery-treeview/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Content/jquery-treeview/jquery.treeview.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#treeview ul").treeview();
    });
</script>
```

the link addresses are okay, because they are not underlined and i checked the path manually. In clear HTML the plugin works. I also tried

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Content/jquery-treeview/jquery-1.2.6.min.js")
or
@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery-treeview/jquery-1.2.6.min.js")
```

At it seems same (not working). Where is the problem ?

But this code works, so JQuery is loaded.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
                alert("ready!");
            });
```

HTML Code

```
<div id="treeview">
        <ul>
            <li>Category
                <ul><li>SubCategory</li></ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery revealed, in Shared/_Layout.cshtml JQuery was also included by default so the solution was comment it out :-)